# Is there a way to remove public access to the form?

Tags: cognito-forms

I am embedding my form behind a secure page but if someone, somehow got access to the form URL, they would be able to process the form (which sends to a webhook).

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the best way to prevent people from accessing your public form is to add some simple password protection - check out this [blog post](http://blog.cognitoforms.com/password-protect-your-forms) for step-by-step instructions on how to do this.

In the future, the [Customer Portal](https://trello.com/c/u5WcAYkd/103-customer-portal) feature (which allows customers to create their own custom logins and restricts form access via username and password) should meet a lot of your needs in this regard.